# Export Mongoose query as an array of nested arrays

Tags: node.js, mongoose, async-await

Good morning,

I thought that following the instructions of [Push element into nested array mongoose nodejs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47511061/push-element-into-nested-array-mongoose-nodejs) I would manage to solve my issue but I am still stuck.

I am trying to get the results of a Mongoose query into an array. The below code works when the number of objects is relatively small, but I get a "parse error" whenever the volumen increases.

I can see I am not considering the fact that the code is asynchronous but my the attemps I have tried end up in `Promise { <pending> }` at best.

```
const Collection = require("./schema");
const connection = require("mongoose");

let data = [];

Collection.find({},(e,result)=>{

        result.forEach(doc =>{ 
        
        data.push([doc["a"],
                   doc["b"]])
    });
})
.then(()=>connection.close())
module.exports = data;
```

The above is obviously wrong, since I am not respecting the async nature of the operation.

I implemented the below function, but I don't understand how I should resolve the promise.

```
async function getdata() {
  const cursor = Collection.find().cursor();
  let data = []
  await cursor.eachAsync(async function(doc) {
    await new Promise(resolve =>resolve((data.push(doc))));
  });
    
}
```

The aim is that when I do `let data = require("./queryResult.js")` `data` contains all the necessary data `[[a,b],[a,b]]`

Could anybody give me a hand on this one?

Many thanks in advance.